# How to disable WOW64 file system redirection for GetModuleFileNameEx?

Tags: c, winapi, wow64

I'm running the following from a 32-bit process on a 64-bit Windows 10:

```
#ifndef _DEBUG
    WCHAR buffPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    FARPROC pfn = (FARPROC)::GetModuleHandleEx;
    HMODULE hMod = NULL;
    ::GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | 
        GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT,
        (LPCTSTR)pfn, &hMod);

    PVOID pOldVal = NULL;
    if(::Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&pOldVal))
    {
        ::GetModuleFileNameEx(::GetCurrentProcess(), hMod, buffPath, _countof(buffPath));
        ::Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(pOldVal);

        wprintf(L"Path=%s\n", buffPath);
    }
#else
#error run_in_release_mode
#endif
```

and I'm expecting to receive the path as `c:\windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.DLL`, but it gives me:

```
Path=C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
```

Any idea why?

Comment: the `GetModuleHandleEx` simply returned saved module name, used for load dll. the `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` have not and can not any effect for this. you can use say `GetMappedFileName` for get real file system path

Comment: @RbMm: Where was it saved in, `PEB` struct? So yeah, `GetMappedFileName` returns the correct path, sort of. It's in device-path form. Do you know of any easy way to convert it to the form used by Explorer, i.e. `C:\ ` instead of `\Device\HardiskVolumeN`? And btw, `GetMappedFileName` doesn't need `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`

Comment: it saved in `_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` the `GetModuleFileNameEx` return from here. even preserve case in file name/path. you can easy test this by self - load some dll and use unusual case combination in name - `GetModuleFileNameEx` - return you exactly this back. when  `GetMappedFileName` - return you true file system path

Comment: @RbMm: `_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` that's in the kernel space, right?

Comment: of course `GetMappedFileName` not depend from `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` too (this is shell over `ZwQueryVirtualMemory(,,MemoryMappedFilenameInformation..)`

Comment: no, `_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` - this is user space

Comment: and for what you need convert nt path to win32 form ?

Comment: @RbMm: Sorry, I was gone for a while. So yeah, like you pretty much surmised in your answer, I need it for the shell APIs.

Comment: for shell api unfortunately need only driver letter path, so need `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS` for convert path

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, thanks. I wish MS had a single API for those conversions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when we load dll via `LoadLibrary[Ex]` or `LdrLoadDll` - first some pre-process transmitted dll name (say convert `api-*` to actual dll name or redirect dll name based on manifest - well known example `comctl32.dll`) and then use this (possible modified) dll name to load file as dll. but wow fs redirection - not preprocessed at this stage. if dll was successfully loaded - system allocate [`LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntldr_8h_source.html#l00102) structure and save transmitted (after pre-process) dll name here as is.

the `GetModuleFileNameEx` simply walk throughout [`LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntldr_8h_source.html#l00102) double linked list and search entry where `DllBase == hModule` - if found - copy `FullDllName` to `lpFilename` (if buffer big enough). so it simply return dll path used during load dll. the `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` have no any effect to this call.

if we want get real (canonical) full path to dll - need use `GetMappedFileNameW` or [`ZwQueryVirtualMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn957455(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`MemoryMappedFilenameInformation`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntmmapi_8h_source.html#l00009)

so code can be (if we hope that `MAX_PATH` is enough)

```
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
GetMappedFileNameW(NtCurrentProcess(), hmod, path, RTL_NUMBER_OF(path));
```

or if use ntapi and correct handle any path length:

```
NTSTATUS GetDllName(PVOID AddressInDll, PUNICODE_STRING NtImageName)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PUNICODE_STRING ImageName;
    };

    static volatile UCHAR guz;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    SIZE_T cb = 0, rcb = 0x200;

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQueryVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), AddressInDll, 
            MemoryMappedFilenameInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            return RtlDuplicateUnicodeString(
                RTL_DUPLICATE_UNICODE_STRING_NULL_TERMINATE, 
                ImageName, NtImageName);
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW);

    return status;
}
    UNICODE_STRING NtImageName;
    if (0 <= GetDllName(hmod, &NtImageName))
    {
        RtlFreeUnicodeString(&NtImageName);
    }
```

about question "way to convert it to the win32 form" - there is a counter question - for what ?
at first we can use it as is with `NtOpenFile` (well documented api), at second - the simplest way convert to win32 form, accepted by `CreateFileW` - add `\\?\globalroot` prefix to nt path. but not all win32 api (primary shell api) accept this form. if we want exactly dos-device form path (aka `X:`) need use [`IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560474(v=vs.85).aspx) - got the array of [`MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562286(v=vs.85).aspx) inside [`MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562288(v=vs.85).aspx) structure and search for DeviceName which is prefix for our nt path and SymbolicLinkName have driver letter form. code can be ~

```
#include <mountmgr.h>

ULONG NtToDosPath(HANDLE hMM, PUNICODE_STRING ImageName, PWSTR* ppsz)
{
    static MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT MountPoint;

    static volatile UCHAR guz;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS pmmp = 0;
    DWORD cb = 0, rcb = 0x200, BytesReturned;

    ULONG err = NOERROR;

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb) cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pmmp = (PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS)alloca(rcb - cb), stack);

        if (DeviceIoControl(hMM, IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS, 
            &MountPoint, sizeof(MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT), 
            pmmp, cb, &BytesReturned, 0))
        {
            if (ULONG NumberOfMountPoints = pmmp->NumberOfMountPoints)
            {
                PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT MountPoints = pmmp->MountPoints;

                do 
                {
                    UNICODE_STRING SymbolicLinkName = {
                        MountPoints->SymbolicLinkNameLength,
                        SymbolicLinkName.Length,
                        (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(pmmp, MountPoints->SymbolicLinkNameOffset)
                    };

                    UNICODE_STRING DeviceName = {
                        MountPoints->DeviceNameLength,
                        DeviceName.Length,
                        (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(pmmp, MountPoints->DeviceNameOffset)
                    };

                    PWSTR FsPath;

                    if (RtlPrefixUnicodeString(&DeviceName, ImageName, TRUE) && 
                        DeviceName.Length < ImageName->Length &&
                        *(FsPath = (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(ImageName->Buffer, DeviceName.Length)) == '\\' &&
                        MOUNTMGR_IS_DRIVE_LETTER(&SymbolicLinkName))
                    {
                        cb = ImageName->Length - DeviceName.Length;

                        if (PWSTR psz = new WCHAR[3 + cb/sizeof(WCHAR)])
                        {
                            *ppsz = psz;

                            psz[0] = SymbolicLinkName.Buffer[12];
                            psz[1] = ':';
                            memcpy(psz + 2, FsPath, cb + sizeof(WCHAR));

                            return NOERROR;
                        }

                        return ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;
                    }

                } while (MountPoints++, --NumberOfMountPoints);
            }

            return ERROR_NOT_FOUND;
        }

        rcb = pmmp->Size;

    } while ((err = GetLastError()) == ERROR_MORE_DATA);

    return err;
}


ULONG NtToDosPath(PWSTR lpFilename, PWSTR* ppsz)
{
    HANDLE hMM = CreateFile(MOUNTMGR_DOS_DEVICE_NAME, FILE_GENERIC_READ, 
        FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (hMM == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    UNICODE_STRING us;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&us, lpFilename);

    ULONG err = NtToDosPath(hMM, &us, ppsz);

    CloseHandle(hMM);

    return err;
}

    PWSTR psz;
    if (NtToDosPath(path, &psz) == NOERROR)
    {
        DbgPrint("%S\n", psz);
        delete [] psz;
    }
```

also we can change in code to `MOUNTMGR_IS_VOLUME_NAME(&SymbolicLinkName)` for get volume (persistent) name form instead driver letter form